# SQL Server and excel date to number conversion give difference

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

In excel for date `31.10.2015` in cell `H9`,  if I put formula in other cell `= H9+A` I receive cell `42308A`.

In SQL Server I use `CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(int, CONVERT(datetime, [Due Date])))` and get `42306`.

Why I get difference of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 reasons.

The first date with a serial number in Excel is 1900-01-01. This has a serial number of 1. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252
In SQL this date has a numeric number of 0 not 1. So that accounts for a difference of 1.

The second unit is a bit odd. In Excel the date 1900-02-29 has a serial number even though that date didn't exist (29th Feb exists every 4 years except at the turn of a century). In SQL 1900-02-29 doesn't exist (try doing this `SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(datetime, '19000229'))`). So that accounts for the second unit difference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually date difference between sql and excel equals to 1. Because of this, in excel `01/01/1900` equals to 1, on the contrary, in sql `01/01/1900` equals to 0. Read this [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_odiagmsv_005.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year

In addition to the shift of the initial index of the date 1900-01-01, there is also a shift due to the fact that Excel historically considers 1900 as a leap year. I.e., there is 29/02/1900 in Excel. there is no such date in SQL.